# spring boot security block static resources after https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https

I've searched a little bit on the forum but I was not able to find something suitable. I recently published my spring boot multi maven project on my server(VPS). Everything was fine, but after I secured the site over HTTPS with Let's Encrypt, the static content of the site is not being served, instead it is blocked (403).
this is my app's structure:

```
app
--api
  --src/main/resources/static
--business
--model
--repository
```

static resources are inside src/main/resources/static folder of the api maven module.

I'm able to reach my site homepage using (for example): https://example-app.com/index.html

js and other resources are on the same level of index.html.

inside my security configuration of spring boot security I have:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

as I said, before https I was perfectly able to run my app, but now when I access my index.html I have many 403 inside the browser console(js, images, css, fonts). As you can see my security configuration is very permissive, so I don't think it's here the problem.
I presume it's a spring boot misconfigured option.

UPDATE

after some testing I saw the rest api called from within the app always end in 403, but if i try to call them outside app context(from url, postman...) they all works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess work but let's see. `httpSecurity.antMatcher(/api/public/**).permitAll()` should only work for users that is already authenticated. Since you use `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` it is possible that the `AuthenticationContext` is not available when you call a resource within your app.

If you don't mind exposing the resources to unauthenticated users, you can try doing this instead:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(/api/public/**);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, unfortunately not working! I'm thinking something about CORS because the problem is FE: when executing the request from postman or curl or similiar it works.. so it's a problem of the client side of the app. I'll let you know if I discover something more